# introduce further approval via prolog if code change exceed defined limitation

Tags: prolog, continuous-integration, gerrit

if code change exceed our define threshold like 300 lines, we would like to introduce new lab like "manager approval".

the logic we used is add "manager approval" by default, this works well;
using prolog submit rule as following logic, as long as code change is less than 300 lines, remove "manager approval“ label.

the testing show that "manager approval" label is there although the code change is less than 300 lines.

rules.pl file:

```
submit_rule(S) :-
    gerrit:default_submit(X),
    X =.. [submit | Ls],
    require_IP(Ls, R),
    S =.. [submit | R].

require_IP(S,R) :-
    gerrit:commit_stats(Files,Insertions,Deletions),
    Insertions < 300,
    gerrit:remove_label(S,label('IP-Approved',_),R), !.
require_IP(S,S).
```

On gerrit server error_log has following error, looks the rules.pl has syntax error i'm new for prolog language, who can share light for us? thanks for help.

attach official remove_label definition from https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/gerrit/blob/master/prolog/gerrit_common.pl

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%
%% remove_label/3:
%%
%%   Removes all occurances of label(Name, Status).
%%
:- public remove_label/3.
%%
remove_label([], _, []) :- !.
remove_label(List, Label, Out) :-
  List = [_ | _],
  !,
  subtract1(List, Label, Out).
remove_label(S, Label, Out) :-
  S =.. [submit | Ls],
  subtract1(Ls, Label, Tmp),
  Out =.. [submit | Tmp].
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

==========================================================
update on 8/30:

we are using three different approach  on gerrit 2.11, no syntax error now. but none of them works, new label keeps there what ever the code change size. Suspect commit_stats() does not on 2.11:
1) which file defines commit_stats() in gerrit source code?
2) any other way to achieve this?

really appreciate any help on this.

solution 1:

% check if submit length is less than 30 lines

```
submit_rule(S) :-
        gerrit:default_submit(X),
        X =.. [submit | Ls],
        require_Manager(Ls, R),
        %S =.. [submit | [label(R, need(_)) ].
        S =.. [submit | R].

require_Manager(S, R) :-
        gerrit:commit_stats(_,added,_),
        %label(added, need(_)),
        added < 30,
        gerrit:remove_label(S,label('Manager-Approval',_),R), !.
require_Manager(S, S).
```

solution 2:

```
 submit_rule(S) :-

        gerrit:default_submit(X),

         X =.. [submit | Ls],

        remove_verified(Ls, R),

        S =.. [submit | R].

 remove_verified([], []).

 remove_verified([label('Manager-Approval', _) | T], R) :- gerrit:commit_stats(_, inserted, _), inserted > 5, remove_verified(T, R), !.

 remove_verified([H|T], [H|R]) :- remove_verified(T, R).
```

solution 3:

```
submit_rule(submit(CR, V, MA)) :-
       gerrit:commit_stats(_, inserted, _), inserted >= 5, !,
        base(CR, V),
       gerrit:max_with_block(-1, 1, 'Manager-Approval', MA).

submit_rule(submit(CR, V)) :-
       base(CR, V).

base(CR, V) :-
       gerrit:max_with_block(-1, 1, 'Verified', V),
       gerrit:max_with_block(-2, 2, 'Code-Review', CR).
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second clause, `Files` and `Deletions` are singleton variables. Thus, you can rewrite the clause as:

```
require_IP(S,R) :-
    gerrit:commit_stats(_,Insertions,_),
    Insertions < 300,
    gerrit:remove_label(S,label('IP-Approved',_),R), !.
```

But there isn't any syntax error. In the log, you have instead a **runtime** error, which occurs apparently when using the first clause. The error seems to be caused by the call to the `gerrit:remove_label/3` predicate not instantiating `R`, which results in error show in the log when `S =.. [submit | R]` is called.

Looking into Gerrit documentation (I'm not familiar with it), notably to examples of use of the `gerrit:remove_label/3` predicate, your code looks correct however. Can the error be caused by code other than the one in your question? Do you get the same error if you comment out the first clause for the `require_IP /2` predicate?

Comment: thanks for echo. you mean comment out 1st clause or only comment out calling require_IP(Ls, R)?

Comment: Commenting out the 1st clause of `require_IP /2` so that the second clause is the only one used. That will make the call to `submit_rule/1` do nothing and will tell you if the bug is actually in your code.

Comment: i did two tests: 1. comment out 1st clause, no gerrit error, and all labels are on UI,  this is expected. right?      2 comment out single line require_IP(Ls, R), still see the gerrit error, but also no any labels on gerrit UI.  i just post official label_remove() definition in original question, looks usage is correct.    i'm not familiar with prolog, what's the meaning of last line: require_IP(S,S). appreciate your help.

Comment: The `require_IP(S,S).` clause is a _catchall_ clause. When `Insertions < 300` is false, Prolog backtracks and tries the next clause, which unifies its two arguments. I.e. if `Insertions < 300` is false, then no changes are computed for the list of labels: the returned list of labels will be the original ones.

Comment: You cannot comment out the call to `require_IP/2` predicates as that will make the variable `R` unbound resulting in an instantiation error at runtime.

Comment: thanks Paulo for your input. i'm still struggling on this but no much progress, as limited dump methods. do you have any suggestion for move further.  i updated with latest prolog code, gerrit does not complain anything in run time, but still did not remove the label if small code change... anyway to check the run time value for the prolog script. thanks a lot!

Comment: Other than a typo in `'IP-Approved'` or some issue in the values returned by the `gerrit:commit_stats/3` predicate, I cannot think of any other reason for your code to be failing.

Comment: thanks Paulo, so anyway for run time debugging? like dump the added value in prolog.

Comment: Maybe try adding the goals `writeq(user_error, gerrit:commit_stats(Files,Insertions,Deletions)), nl(user_error)` after the call to the predicate?

Comment: P.S. If the Prolog system embedded in Gerrit doesn't support the `user_error` stream alias just drop it and use instead `writeq(gerrit:commit_stats(Files,Insertions,Deletions)), nl`.